# Golang proper use of interfaces

Tags: go, dns

I am new to Go and am running into a situation that I am unsure how to solve. I am working on some code that takes a DNS packet in raw bytes and returns a struct called DNSPacket.

The struct looks like the following

```
type DNSPacket struct {
    ...some fields
    Questions  []Question
    Answers    []Answer
    ...some more fields
}
```

The issue I am having is with the Answers type which looks like this.

```
 type Answer struct {
    Name     string
    Type     int
    Class    int
    TTL      uint32
    RdLength int
    Data     []byte
}
```

Depending on the type of Answer the `Data` field must be decoded differently. For example if the Answer is an `A` record (Type 1) the data is simply an ipv4 address. However if the Answer is an `SRV` record (Type 33) then the data is contains `port`, `priority`, `weight` and `target` encoded in the byte slice.

I thought it would be great if I could have a method on Answer called `DecodeData()` that returns the correct data depending on the type, however since there is no overriding or inheritance in Go I am unsure how to solve this. I tried using an interface to solve this, but it would not compile. I tried something like

```
type DNSRecordType interface {
    Decode(data []byte)
}


type RecordTypeSRV struct {
   target string
   ...more fields
}
//to 'implement' the DNSRecordType interface
func (record *RecordTypeSRV) Decode(data []byte) {
    //do the work to decode appropriately and set
    //the fields on the record
}
```

Then in the Answer method

```
func (a *Answer) DecodeData() DNSRecordType {
    if a.Type === SRVType {
       record := RecordTypeSRV{}
       record.Decode(a.Data)
       return record
    }

    //do something similar for other record types
 }
```

What would be the correct Go way of having a single Answer type, but be able to return different types of Answer Data depending on their type?
Sorry, if this is a completely beginner question as I am still very new to Go.

Thanks!

Comment: Normally this sort of thing is done with a *Discriminated Union,* but I don't know if there is such a thing in Go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me summarize your question.

You have a DNS Packet with the list of Answers. Based on the type of answer you have to process the data in the answer.

```
type DNSPacket struct {
    ...some fields
    Questions  []Question
    Answers    []Answer
    ...some more fields
}
type Answer struct {
    Name     string
    Type     int
    Class    int
    TTL      uint32
    RdLength int
    Data     []byte
}
```

**Answer** 
Let's create an interface that should be implemented to process data.

```
type PacketProcessor interface {
    Process(Answer)
}
```

Let SRV implements the PacketProcessor

```
type SRV struct {
    ...
}

func (s *SRV) Process(a Answer) {
    ...
}
```

Your processing logic should be as follows

```
func (a *Answer) Process() {
    var p PacketProcessor
    switch a.Type {
        case SRVType:
        p = &SRV{}
        ...
        //other cases
    }

    //finally
    p.Process(*a)
}
```

Hope it helps :). 
There is a Gurgaon based golang community that is always ready to help developers with their problems.
You can join the community via [slack](https://join.slack.com/t/golang-gurgaon/shared_invite/enQtNDE4Njk5OTAzMjIwLWM0MjBkMzlhYjVhNDRiZmMzYTc5NDkzODMwZmMyOGRhMjA0NjM3NDcwNTcwMzY5MjA3YzcyZTA4MWU2MWQyYjk)

Comment: You hit the nail on the head with summarizing my issue. I expanded on the `Process` method so the signature looks like this now `func (a *Answer) Process() PacketProcessor {...}` . That way the consumer of the Answer can use the resulting value. I have something like this working, but as you see I need to do type asserting. `record := decoded.Answers[0].Process()
t, ok := record.(*dnsPacket.RecordTypeA)`

Answer (score 1):

As I know, to return different types, the return param must be an interface. So you can simply declare the function like this:

```
func (a *Answer) DecodeData() (mode modeType, value interface{}) {}
```

**mode** means the value is A record or SRV record, and you can return anything you want with the **value** field.

The function caller can handle the **value** depending on **mode**

If you want the code be more elegant, you can define different value structs for each mode. Then the caller may act as below:

```
type modeType int

const (
    ARecord modeType = 1
    SRVRecord modeType = 2
)

switch mode {
    case ARecord:
    // do something
    case SRVRecord:
    // do something
}
```